# Is there a way to solve the following series?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I was solving a question related to permutation and combination and I came across the following series.
$$\binom{n}{0}k^0+2\binom{n}{1}k^1+3\binom{n}{2}k^2+...+(n+1)\binom{n}{n}k^n$$

Is there a way to solve the series?

Comment: By noting $\binom{n}{i}i = \binom{n-1}{i-1}n$, you can also sum series.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** it is the derivative of $k(1+k)^n$

Answer (score 0):

For $r\ge1,$

$$(r+1)\binom nr=r\binom nr+\binom nr$$

$$=\binom nr+r\cdot\dfrac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{r\cdot(r-1)!\{n-1-(r-1)\}!}=\binom nr+n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^n(r+1)\binom nrk^r=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nrk^r+nk\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}k^{r-1}$$

Now use $\displaystyle(a+b)^m=\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mra^{m-r}b^r$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\pars{\ell + 1}k^{\ell} & =
\partiald{}{k}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}k^{\ell + 1} =
\partiald{\bracks{k\pars{1 + k}^{n}}}{k} =
\pars{1 + k}^{n} + k\bracks{n\pars{1 + k}^{n - 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\pars{n + 1}k + 1}\pars{1 + k}^{n - 1}}
\end{align}