# How to solve a summation problem involving binomial coefficient and powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, combinations

The problem is as follows:

$\textrm{Find the value of n in the summation:}$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}=2^{n+4}$$

So far I only know the definition of the binomial coefficient as this:

$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-k)!}$

But if I replace the above in the problem ends like this:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

From then on I'm lost. How to solve that situation?.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507192/is-there-a-way-to-solve-the-following-series/2507217#2507217

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you propose an answer to the problem?. I have read the link you had shown but I don't get very clear the idea of how the definition of $$(a+b)^{m}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{m}{n}a^{m-r}b^{n}$$ applies to this problem. Can you offer some help?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that, by Newton's formula
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$$
and so you can impose
$$2^{n+4} = 16 \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = \sum_{r=0}^n (2r+1) \binom{n}{r}.$$
Thus
$$\sum_{r=0}^n (15-2r)\binom{n}{r} = 0.$$
From here it is clear that $n = 15$, just expand the sum and see the symmetry:
\begin{align}
& +15\binom{15}{0}+13\binom{15}{1}+11\binom{15}{2}+9\binom{15}{3}+\dots+\binom{15}{7} + \\
&-15\binom{15}{15}-13\binom{15}{14}-11\binom{15}{13}-9\binom{15}{12}-\dots-\binom{15}{8}.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you add more steps between $$16\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}-\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(15-2r)\binom{n}{r}$$ I don't know how to prove that. The final line in your answer I'm also stuck there how do I conclude $n=15$? Is it because there is a $15$ in the summation from the preceding line? Can you also explain this with more details?.

Comment: About the sum: just write $\sum_{r=0}^n 16\binom{n}{r}-(2r+1)\binom{n}{r} = \sum_{r=0}^n (16-1-2r)\binom{n}{r}$. Write it explicitly with a particular $n$ if you don't get the steps, but should be clear now. 
I conclude $n = 15$ because I see that as $r$ grows I get positive numbers which should cancel at some point. So $2r$ has to go over 15 for sure. So I expect that $15\binom{n}{0}$ (first term) cancel with a negative term like $-15\binom{n}{n}$, and guess what, I get the factor $-15$ when $r = n = 15$, This is my intuition in this case.

Comment: Okay I got the idea regarding the sum but the second part shouldn't it be $2r=15$? The rest about $r=n$ its clear but since its half of $2r$ it doesn't seem right as $15$. I'm stuck at this reasoning..

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my previous comment but I get your idea as in the second part the number you were referring comes from $15-2r=-15$, hence $-2r=-30$, therefore $r=15$ right?. The rest I understand about $r=n$.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}}
> &=2\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n}{r}r+\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\tag{1}\\
> &=2n\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}+2^n\tag{2}\\
> &=2n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{r}+2^n\tag{3}\\
> &=2n\cdot 2^{n-1}+2^n\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=(n+1)2^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply out. We also start the lower limit of the left-hand sum with $r=1$ which is admissible since we have the factor $0$ in case $r=0$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}$. We also apply the binomial theorem in the form
  $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}1^r1^{n-r}=(1+1)^n=2^n$.
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $r=0$.
- In (4) we again apply the binomial theorem in the form $(1+1)^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative approach:

$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}=\frac{d}{dx}\left.\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}x^{2r+1}\right|_{x=1}=\frac{d}{dx}\left.x(1+x^2)^n\right|_{x=1}=2^n(n+1)$$
hence if this number equals $2^n\cdot 16$ we must have $n=\color{red}{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}$$
Reversing the order of summation(summing backwards) we have:
$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2(n-r)+1)\binom{n}{n-r}$$

Since $$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$$
We have$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2(n-r)+1)\binom{n}{r}$$

Now $$2S= \sum_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}+ \sum_{r=0}^{n}(2(n-r)+1)\binom{n}{r}$$
$$=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(2n+2)\binom{n}{r}$$
Hence $$S= \sum_{r=0}^{n}(n+1)\binom{n}{r}=(n+1) 2^{n}$$

Now Let $(n+1)2^n = 2^{n+4}$, then $n+1= 16$, hence $n=15$

Comment: I tried to understand your answer but I don't know how does $\sum_{r=0}^{n}(n+1)\binom{n}{r}$ becomes into $(n+1)\times2^{n}$? The $2S$ part I get that goes into the sum and divides by $2$ what is inside the bracket $2n+2$. But the way to reach to the right side of your final equation is not very clear to me.

Comment: You know that $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = 2^n$, $\sum_{r=0}^n (n+1) \binom{n}{r}$ is just $(n+1)$ times $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}$ because $(n+1)$ is a constant, is it can be pulled out of the summation.